# Automatic backups (history) in LibreOffice (OpenOffice)

Tags: backup, macros, openoffice, libreoffice, openoffice-writer

LibreOffice can create a backup copy when you enable it in settings (Options > Load/Save > General), but it saves only the previous state (one only).

It has also an versioning feature (File -> Versions). This works very well, but but you have to save a version manually or enable option to automatically create version on close.
This feature is disabled by default, and even if enabled, saves a version only on close, not on each save.

I'd like to have it automatically enabled, and triggered upon each save or lets say each 5 minutes. Is there an option to do this? Maybe some kind of macro?

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly a legitimate functionality (I've just lost a few hours worth of work in LO Writer after non recoverable crash, which is why I'm searching fo such a solution), but strangely enough I haven't been able to find a perfect solution. The closest might be the following macro published 6 years ago, so I don't know if it will be compatible "out of the box" with current LO versions:
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=23531

Ideally this would be triggered automatically when File->Save is activated, prefereably even through the "auto-save every X minutes" feature...